# Obtaining the pdf from the moment generating function

Tags: moment-generating-functions

We have, for a positive random variable X:

$$ M_X(t) = E \left[\text{e}^{tX}\right] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!} E \left[ X^k\right] $$

Then, the pdf is given by:

$$ f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \lim_{T\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\gamma + iT} \text{e}^{-tx} M_X(t) dt = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{E \left[ X^k\right]}{2\pi i} \lim_{T\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\gamma + iT} \text{e}^{-tx}  \frac{t^k}{k!} dt $$

This is correct? If it is, how can I calculate the inverse laplace transform of $t^k$? I just found the solution when k is non-integer and negative. Thanks!

Comment: Can you not use the derivative $\rightarrow$ multiplication property from here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems

Comment: How I can use this property? thanks

Comment: Are you not taking inverse laplace of polynomials on the right hand side?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking of using the derivative property. But the pdf will be expanded with the derivative of delta dirac functions

Comment: Is it $\int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}T}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}T}$ in the integral?

Comment: the random variable is positive, but no problem in consider this interval

Comment: @Felipe   Do you think that $\int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}T}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}T} \mathrm{e}^{-tx} t^k \mathrm{d}t$ does not exist, and so we can not obtain $f_X(x)$ in this way?

Comment: I'm using $\int_{0}^{\gamma + iT} $ because my Va is positive. But when i tried, with fourier transform, I get a series with derivatives of delta dirac. In reality, I'm trying to obtain the pdf from the moments of the Random variable. But, it seems to broke somewhere

Comment: @Felipe (You may use @ otherwise I don't know your reply.)  Consider the exponential distribution with PDF $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-x}1_{x > 0}$. We have $F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(x) \mathrm{e}^{sx} \mathrm{d} x = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-(1-s)x} \mathrm{d} x
= \frac{1}{1-s}$ when $\mathrm{Re}(1-s) > 0$. We have for $x > 0$,
$
\frac{1}{2\pi \mathrm{i}}\int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}\infty}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}\infty}
\mathrm{e}^{-sx}F(s) ds = \frac{1}{2\pi \mathrm{i}}\int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}\infty}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}\infty}
\mathrm{e}^{-sx} \frac{1}{1-s} ds = \mathrm{e}^{-x}.
$

Comment: @Felipe Alternatively, with the substitution $s = \gamma + \mathrm{i}u$, then $\int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}\infty}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}\infty} \cdots \mathrm{d} s = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots \mathrm{d}u$, we get the same result.

Comment: @RiverLi I was trying to obtain an expansion of the pdf $f_X(x)$ from its moments. But that last integral give the derivatives of delta function, but it dont make sense for me. Note that i'm not trying to obtain the pdf from MGF with laplace transform

Comment: @RiverLi The reasoning is the following: if I have the pdf constructed from its moments, I can estimate the behavior of the pdf from the estimated moments. But it seems not so trivial

Comment: @Felipe  In my opinion, $\int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}T}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}T} \mathrm{e}^{-tx} t^k \mathrm{d}t$ does not exist, you can not obtain $f_X(x)$ in this way.

Comment: @Felipe  Actually, you want to interchange the order of integration and summation, i.e.
$\int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}\infty}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}\infty}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi \mathrm{i}}\mathrm{e}^{-tx}\frac{t^k}{k!}\mathrm{E}[X^k] \mathrm{d}t
\overset{?} =
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\int_{\gamma - \mathrm{i}\infty}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi \mathrm{i}}\mathrm{e}^{-tx}\frac{t^k}{k!}\mathrm{E}[X^k] \mathrm{d}t.
$
I think that the answer is negative.

Comment: @RiverLi, Yes, the moments don't integrate. You know why this equality is broken? Thanks for the answers

Comment: @Felipe    The existence of the integral for each $k$ may be crucial.